# reading csv file without for

Tags: python, csv

I need to read a CSV file in python.

Since for last row I receive a 'NULL byte' error I would like to avoid using for keyword but the while.

Do you know how to do that?

```
    reader = csv.reader( file )
    for row in reader  # I have an error at this line
          # do whatever with row
```

I want to substitute the for-loop with a while-loop so that I can check if the row is NULL or not.

What is the function for reading a single row in the CSV module?
Thanks

Thanks

p.S. below the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FetchNeuro_TodayTrades.py", line 189, in 
    for row in reader:
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
```

Comment: I never had a problem with a for loop. Please add the actual code, plus the traceback, so we can tell what you are really doing.

Comment: I can confirm the reader chokes on a NULL byte written to the file as chr(0).  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 11, in <module>
    for line in reader:
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte

Comment: @telliott: There is no such thing as a NULL byte.

Comment: My bad:  is "null character" OK?

Comment: No, there's no such thing as "null character". It is a valid character. Its ASCII name is "NUL".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Maybe you could catch the exception raised by the CSV reader. Something like this:

```
filename = "my.csv"
reader = csv.reader(open(filename))
try:
    for row in reader:
        print 'Row read with success!', row
except csv.Error, e:
    sys.exit('file %s, line %d: %s' % (filename, reader.line_num, e))
```

Or you could use `next()`:

```
while True:
    try: 
        print reader.next()
    except csv.Error:
        print "Error"
    except StopIteration:
        print "Iteration End"
        break
```

Comment: Hi Pedro!
Great! It is what I was looking for!
AFG

Comment: You cannot catch this exception (test it).

Comment: @Pedro: What @telliott99 means (if I'm channeling him correctly) is that you need to do `import _csv` then `except _csv.Error:`

Comment: Ah...  <whacks self on head>  The issue is that import csv does not import _csv, and that's why I couldn't catch the exception?  Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @telliot99: WHAT "doesn't seem to work"?? Show code that demonstrates "could'nt catch the exception". If you're having difficulty, try asking a separate question!

Comment: Weird: when I use the `next()` solution, I get `AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'next'`. What could that mean?

Answer (score 4):

You need (always) to say EXACTLY what is the error message that you got. Please edit your question.

Probably this:

```
>>> import csv; csv.reader("\x00").next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
>>>
```

The csv module is not 8-bit clean; see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html): """Also, there are currently some issues regarding ASCII NUL characters."""

The error message is itself in error: it should be "NUL", not "NULL" :-(

If the last line in the file is empty, you won't get an exception, you'll merely get `row == []`.

Assuming the problem is one or more NULs in your file(s), you'll need to (1) speak earnestly to the creator(s) of your file(s) (2) failing that, read the whole file in (mode="rb"), strip out the NUL(s), and feed `fixed_text.splitlines()` to the csv reader.

Comment: Hi!
You are right! FOr the sake of clarity I added my question with the Traceback. I solved at the end with a try/except solutoin

Answer (score 2):

The Django community has addressed Python CSV import issues, so it might be worth [searching for CSV import](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/django-users/search?group=django-users&q=csv+import&qt_g=Search+this+group) there, or posting a question. Also, you could edit the offending line directly in the CSV file before trying the import.

Answer (score 2):

You could try cleaning the file as you read it:

```
def nonull(stream):
    for line in stream:
        yield line.replace('\x00', '')

f = open(filename)
reader = csv.reader(nonull(f))
```

Assuming, of course, that simply ignoring NULL characters will work for you!

Comment: @John Fouhy: Without testing, I wouldn't rely on that approach working if fields had embedded newlines, ESPECIALLY as you don't ensure binary mode ('rb').

Comment: A fair point, although I'd imagine a lot of software chokes on CSV files with newlines embedded inside fields..

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is specific to the last line being empty, you can use numpy.genfromtxt (or the old matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec)

```
$: cat >csv_file.txt
foo,bar,baz
yes,no,0
x,y,z



$:
$: ipython
>>> from numpy import genfromtxt
>>> genfromtxt("csv_file.txt", dtype=None, delimiter=',')
array([['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
       ['yes', 'no', '0'],
       ['x', 'y', 'z']], 
      dtype='|S3')
```

Answer (score 0):

not really sure what you mean, but you can always check for existence with if

```
>>> reader = csv.reader("file")
>>> for r  in reader:
...   if r: print r
...
```

if this is not what you want, you should describe your problem more clearly by showing examples of things that doesn't work for you, including sample file format and desired output you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer, but I can confirm the problem, and that most answers posted don't work.  You cannot catch this exception.  You cannot test for `if line`.  Maybe you could check for the NULL byte directly, but I'm not swift enough to do that...  If it is always on the last line, you could of course skip that.

```
import csv
FH = open('data.csv','wb')
line1 = [97,44,98,44,99,10]
line2 = [100,44,101,44,102,10]
for n in line1 + line2:
    FH.write(chr(n))
FH.write(chr(0))
FH.close()
FH = open('data.csv')
reader = csv.reader(FH)
for line in reader:
    if '\0' in line:  continue
    if not line:  continue
    print line

$ python script.py 
['a', 'b', 'c']
['d', 'e', 'f']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 11, in <module>
    for line in reader:
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
```

Comment: Hi!
I tried the simple try/except approach. In my case it was easy and good since I have an error on the last line of a CSV file where there is no valid data. I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Process the initial `csv` file and replace the `Nul '\0'` with blank, and then you can read it.
The actual code looks like this:

```
data_initial = open(csv_file, "rU")
reader = csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in data_initial))
```

It works for me.

And the original answer is here:[csv-contain null byte](http://taombo.com/taombo-blog/reading-null-values-with-csv.reader-giving-line-contains-null-byte)