# Converting python for loop to while loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to convert for loop to while loop in python and I am not very sure how to do it. Need some help here, thanks! This is what I am working with :

```
with open('name.csv') as labelcsv:
    reader = csv.reader(labelcsv)
    name = []
    namenumber = []
    for row in reader:
        tags.append(row[0])
        namenumber.append(row[1])
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: `reader` has built-in funcions specially for `for-loop` so may not be easy to create `while-loop`.

Comment: duplicate of [reading csv file without for](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2243655/1248974)

Comment: Is it possible that you explain what this code does

    for row in reader:
        tags.append(row[0])
        namenumber.append(row[1])

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what's benefit to change it

```
with open('name.csv') as labelcsv:
    reader = csv.reader(labelcsv)
    name = []
    namenumber = []
    row = next(reader, None)
    while row:
        tags.append(row[0])
        namenumber.append(row[1])
        row = next(reader, None)
```

read more: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next