# Adding a error message in Python as well as commands

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv

# a file in the current directory
FILENAME = "contacts.csv"

def write_contacts(contacts):
with open(FILENAME, "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(contacts)

def read_contacts():
    contacts = []
    with open(FILENAME, newline="") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        contacts.append(row)
return contacts

def list_contacts(contacts):
    for i in range (len(contacts)):
    contact= contacts[i]
    print(str(i+1) +"."+ contact[0])
   print()


 def view_contact(contacts):
    pos = int(input("Number: "))
    if not (pos-1)in range(len(contacts)):
    print(str(pos) + ' not in list, try again')
    view(contacts)
    return
   contact = []
   print(name + email + phone+".\n")
   print()

 def delete_contact(contacts):
    index = int(input("Number: "))
    contact = contacts.pop(index -1)
    write_contacts(contacts)
    print(contact[0]+" was deleted.\n")





 def add_contact(contacts):
    name=input("Name: ")
    email=input("Email: ")
    phone=input("Phone number: ")
    contact= []
    contact.append(name)
    contact.append(email)
    contacts.append(contact)
    write_contacts(contacts)
    print(name + " was added.\n")




 def display_menu():
    print("Contact Manager")
    print()
    print("COMMAND MENU")
    print("list - List all contacts")
    print("view  - View a contact")
    print("add  - Add a contact")
    print("delete- Delete a contact")
    print()
    print()


def main():
   display_menu()
   contacts = read_contacts()
    while True:
      command = input("Command: ")
      if command.lower() == "list":
           list_contacts(contacts)
       elif command.lower()== "view":
          view_contact(contacts)           
       elif command.lower()== "add":
           add_contact(contacts)
        elif command.lower()== "delete":
           delete_contact(contacts)                
           break
        else:
            print("Not a valid command. Please try again.\n")
       print("Bye!")

  if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

This all my code. I'm trying to figure out how to make the delete and view commands display an error message when the user enters a number that is invalid but it's not working. I'm also trying to view a contact when the user selects a specific number form list which would then display the email name and phone number of that selected number. I'm currently stuck

The errors im getting are

raceback (most recent call last):
  , line 93, in 
    main()
  , line 81, in main
    view_contact(contacts)
 , line 32, in view_contact
    view(contacts)
NameError: name 'view' is not defined

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! You have included a lot of code in your post. We, as helpers, were not with you when you wrote that code, and we do not know the intent of it. Likewise, you, since you are the owner of what you have written, are familiar with what is important and what is not. Review your code, figure out what parts are of most importance to your question, then simplify your code to an [MCVE]. This will help us help you if you isolate your situation and only give the relevant code, which should be simple for you yet save us loads of time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you has a good start with list into cvs using append, anyway is your example.

1. You can use ***remove*** to remove your contact from list, see examples with list: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/06/python-list
2. when the user select a specific number from list , just read by stepping to the number phone because you add with: name + email + phone.
3. adding an error message , use: **try except finally**

Comment: How would i give it an erros mesage when the number specified is not there

Comment: Do you want to show you how to check a specific number phone from your csv with try ? Take a look and see if is similar with your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243655/reading-csv-file-without-for